# Problems with Ajax get Request

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have problems with this function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$.get("http://www.boersenpoint.de/pages/charts/shareSupplier.php?request=topFlop",     {     indexName: "DAX" } ,function(data){   
  $(data).find('share').each(function(){
 alert('');
 });

 });
 });
 </script>
 </head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Firebug can not find any errors. By theory 4 alerts should appear, but the don't. Why?

Comment: And what is in your data? If I try that url, I get nothing. That is, just an empty XML document with just the topflop document root.

Comment: tips: .find( selector ),$( selector ),$( element ). "share" is a selector? Then "data" is a selector or a node?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).  This means that you cannot do AJAX requests to a domain unless the page you are on is also on that domain.

The easiest way to get around it would be to set up a script on your server that proxied the requests -- you make a request to your server, the server makes the request to the other server and feeds the response back to you.

If the remote server supports it, you could also use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), but I doubt that is possible as the page is an XML document.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $.get("http://www.boersenpoint.de/pages/charts/shareSupplier.php?request=topFlop", {indexName: "DAX"}, function(data) {
    $(data).find('share').each(function(){
      alert('');
    });
  });
});
```

There are a couple problems with your code...

1. You are making a remote request via ajax which is explicitly prohibited by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
2. EVEN IF you weren't violating that policy, that doesn't guarantee you'd see an alert - what if `data` is empty? If so, `.find('share').each` would not execute ==> no alert.
3. Some browsers (mostly really old ones) actually ignore the `alert();` statement if it doesn't contain text (I don't know about the empty string as you have though, just something to keep in mind).

To summarize, your specific problem in this case is the same-origin policy violation. 2. and 3. are for your benefit in future development.